# Setting System properties on Android using SystemProperties.set() to change ADB to TCP

Tags: android, tcp, adb, root, system-properties

I have an app that is installed on rooted tablets and that goes on their `/system/app/` folder. Therefore it has system-app privileges. I would like to use the `SystemProperties.set()` to change the value of "service.adb.tcp.port" to something other than -1, so ADB runs on the specified TCP port instead of running on USB.

I can use `SystemProperties.get()` without a problem but when it comes to use the `SystemProperties.set()` the app runs the code but does nothing on the property it was supposed to set.

Also, I've included the following permissions on the app:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`

Is there something I'm missing? Any advice will be appreciated.